# IF ELSE using N-channel MOSFET

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, schematic

The situation I have is like this. Let's say I have one input A, one switch B and two outputs C and D (with pull-ups). If B is pressed and A is high I want C only to go low but if A is low I only want D to go low.

I would like to use only N-channel MOSFETs and resistors or a simple IC (no microcontroller), but I'm overheating my head trying to build this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is switch B connected to. Why not draw a schematic to provide clarity.

Comment: Do you know how to build your desired circuit out of logic gates? And do you know how to build logic gates out of n-MOSFETs?

Comment: I believe that what B is connected to is irrelevant,  it's just a switch pulled up and goes low when activated or whatever makes sense to the circuit.

Comment: I thought about logic gates but they only work for logic 1,  right? I would need an inverter on the input A to be used on one of the gates right?

Comment: Whether B is pulled up and goes low when activated, or the other way around, makes a big difference to how the circuit could be constructed.

Comment: "I thought about logic gates but they only work for logic 1, right?" - No, wrong. Normal logic gates work on 0's and 1's.

Comment: From your description is seems like D == A. If A is low then D is low, and if A is high then D is high. B doesn't have any effect on D, so you can implement that part with nothing more than a wire connecting A to D.